# Efficient way to store all users into Redis instead of marshalling an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, redis, marshalling

I am current using Rails.cache.fetch, with the cache_store using redis-store gem (modified to use YAML instead of marshalling normally). Right now, I have the following code:

```
    Rails.cache.fetch("foobar", expires_in: 1.week) do
      User.all.to_a.each do |user|
       user.email = "foobar"
      end
    end
```

This in will store a YAML version of a ruby array of Users into a single key value. I would like to efficiently break up this list into multiple keys, with the idea of being able to retrieve all the values later instead of hitting the database.

How should I do this? I was thinking about a list of hashes, but it doesn't seem efficient as I still would need to look up a specific hash in the list to update just one user.

Comment: Can you elaborate the idea on why you judged saving all users the given way is not desired? What are your goals (metrics) in changing the approach? What for you need to break up the list? Your question doesn't state limits and measures.

Comment: @PavelBulanov Basically, from what I gather on Redis, it is not meant to be storing a huge amount of data into one string. Instead, it should be using a list. 

Redis-store only supports marshalling everything into Strings, rather than supporting lists and hashes.

I wanted to manually cache it using the Redis client, and am not sure what an efficient way to organize an array of potentially thousands of users is. I need to be able to look up any user by an attribute, and fetch the rest of their data through Redis.

Comment: For deep answer, pls provide explanation on why are you using cache at all. What are your read queries, why is it Redis and not regular database, why do you use caching at all (are your requests slow? which one?).

Comment: Normally, if you need just individual users (i.e. read and write per one object), why would you not use regular DB? And you can use redis to cache some widely-used queries result, e.g. Top 10 users (and not query DB each time), etc.

Answer (score 2):

As i understand from your comment:

> I need to be able to look up any user by an attribute, and fetch the rest of their data through Redis.

You want find user in store by some attribute, let's assume that it will be email.
So you can use [redis hash data](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro) structure to complete your task.

There are two simple commands to work with structure:

1. `HGET` which works in `O(1)`
2. `HSET` which works in `O(1)`

So you can see that performance is well.

Example via redis-cli:

```
hmset user:1000 username antirez birthyear 1977 verified 1 => OK
hget user:1000 username => antirez
```

Redis gem (i've checked on 3.2.1 version) has interface to working with this structure.

> A hash with a few fields (where few means up to one hundred or so) is
> stored in a way that takes very little space, so you can store
> millions of objects in a small Redis instance.
>
> While Hashes are used
> mainly to represent objects, they are capable of storing many
> elements, so you can use Hashes for many other tasks as well. Every
> hash can store up to 232 - 1 field-value pairs (more than 4 billion).

Comment: Okay, on my latest attempt this is exactly what I've done. Now my question is: Is it necessarily "bad" to have a key for each user? Should I be doing some complex hash of hashes, or is having one key being a map for each user's data good enough? Here's what the data looks like: http://imgur.com/wVMUcXn

Inside each is a mapping of data I need, like wins and losses.

Comment: Storing many entries in Redis is ok, check [here](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/12202313862/storing-hundreds-of-millions-of-simple-key-value) for extreme example. Same time, just again, reconsider why at all you moved to cache vs regular DB.

Comment: @njny store one hash per each user.

Comment: @PavelBulanov I stored it in cache because these are statistics for each week, and they get completely flushed every week to begin tracking again. It also isn't important if something happens to the cache, and it gets lost. It needs to be fast since the website will access it all at once.

Comment: @farhatmihalko So in the picture I linked, this is one hash per user correct? Or did I do something differently?

Comment: Maybe you still can get more details to your request. Currently question sounds like you're saving _users_ to Redis, which seems to be not true based on your comments. What kind of values (give examples) do you store? Is it week statistics (i.e. set of static value for the whole week) or dynamic values that get added / removed frequently? Again, why you came to idea of caching? You can easily clean-up regular DB on a regular basis. Why is it caching?

Comment: @njny yes, you can use user id or user email as key